# DLL Import error-Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dllimport, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to import VLC in Qt. The errors that I am facing while running the program are:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl VlcMediaPlayer::VlcMediaPlayer(class VlcInstance *)" (__imp_??0VlcMediaPlayer@@QEAA@PEAVVlcInstance@@@Z) referenced in function main

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl VlcMediaPlayer::~VlcMediaPlayer(void)" (__imp_??1VlcMediaPlayer@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl VlcMediaPlayer::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GVlcMediaPlayer@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl VlcMediaPlayer::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@VlcMediaPlayer@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl VlcMediaPlayer::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@VlcMediaPlayer@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl VlcMediaPlayer::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@VlcMediaPlayer@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
```

The code (main.cpp) is given below:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "vlc.h"
#include "libvlc.h"
#include "MediaPlayer.h"
#include "Video.h"
#include "Common.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
//    MainWindow w;
//    w.show();
    VlcInstance *instance;
    VlcMediaPlayer *player=new VlcMediaPlayer(instance);



    return a.exec();
}
```

The **.pro** file is given below:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-01-31T15:09:35
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui multimedia

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Wontwork
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += debug_and_release
CONFIG += build_all

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h\
libvlc.h \
    vlc.h


FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/release/ -lvlc-qt
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/debug/ -lvlc-qt
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/ -lvlc-qt

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/debug

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/release/ -lvlc-qt-widgets
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/debug/ -lvlc-qt-widgets
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/ -lvlc-qt-widgets

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../Qt/libvlc/debug
```

What should I do to get it to run properly?

Comment: Did you see this full example on VideoLan Wiki page: https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Qt/

Comment: @DNT Saw it. Did not help, followed the steps.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? @PrakharMohanSrivastava

Comment: @MohamedKhamis sadly I did not.